# Using Square's Tape library how do i handle calling abstract classes

Tags: android, square-tape

I'm using [Square's Tape library](https://github.com/square/tape) and i've run in to a requirement where i basically need to have an abstract TapeTask class. The problem though is that the deserialization process for the GsonConverter (which implements the library's FileObjectQueue.Converter - as demonstrated in the [sample project](https://github.com/square/tape/blob/master/tape-sample/src/main/java/com/squareup/tape/sample/GsonConverter.java)) doesn't play well with interfaces/abstract classes.

I thought it was a Gson deserialization problem so i registered my Gson instance with a custom TypeAdapter, but that still doesn't do the trick. I figure it has something to do with the FileObjectQueue.Converter.

I'm currently trying to work around this problem, with a nasty wrapper callback interface from my sub-tasks.

My requirement is to have a single TapeQueue and be able to send in multiple types of tasks. So I have a TapeTask abstract class and have concrete implementations like ImageDownloadTask, ImageUploadTask, UrlPostWithRetrofitTask, GoogleAnalyticsTrackerTask ... etc. all going in to a single queue.

Is there a way to achieve this. I guess my question boils down to:
**What do i need to do to make the FileObjectQueue.Converter play well with abstract classes**?

*hint* :P : The javadoc for that class says *"..you need to also include the concrete class name in the serialized byte array"* but i'm not sure what that means. If anyone could post an explanation of how the name can be included in the serialized byte array, in a way that achieves my purpose, i'd be grateful!

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and wrote an Abstract Gson Convertor. I don't think it's super-efficient but gets the job done:

```
/**
 * Use GSON to serialize classes to a bytes.
 *
 * This variant of {@link GsonConverter} works with anything you throw at it.
 * It is however important for Gson to be able to understand your inner complex objects/entities
 * Use an {@link InterfaceAdapter} for these purposes.
 *
 */
public class GsonAbstractClassConverter<T>
    implements FileObjectQueue.Converter<T> {

    public static final String CONCRETE_CLASS_NAME = "concrete_class_name";
    public static final String CONCRETE_CLASS_OBJECT = "concrete_class_object";
    private final Gson _gson;

    public GsonAbstractClassConverter(Gson gson) {
        _gson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    public T from(byte[] bytes) {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        JsonObject completeAbstractClassInfoAsJson = _gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);

        Class<T> clazz;
        try {
            String className = completeAbstractClassInfoAsJson.get(CONCRETE_CLASS_NAME).getAsString();
            clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error while deserializing TapeTask to a concrete class");
            return null;
        }

        String objectDataAsString = completeAbstractClassInfoAsJson.get(CONCRETE_CLASS_OBJECT)
                                                                   .getAsString();

        return _gson.fromJson(objectDataAsString, clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void toStream(T object, OutputStream bytes) throws IOException {
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(bytes);

        JsonObject completeAbstractClassInfoAsJson = new JsonObject();
        completeAbstractClassInfoAsJson.addProperty(CONCRETE_CLASS_NAME, object.getClass().getName());
        completeAbstractClassInfoAsJson.addProperty(CONCRETE_CLASS_OBJECT, _gson.toJson(object));

        _gson.toJson(completeAbstractClassInfoAsJson, writer);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever I try to peek a task using this code I get a NPE on "completeAbstractClassInfoAsJson.get(CONCRETE_CLASS_NAME).getAsString();" any idea why?

Comment: Probably because ur json parsing is failing? Hope u noticed the caveat on using interface adapters if you have complex entities. I would first suggest trying to make sure you can covert to and from json.  If you're able to do that then your problem should go away